# В чем ошибка? JavaScript не выдает нужный результат (возведение в степень)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Консоль выдает ошибку:

> stepen.html:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
>       at stepen.html:56

```html
<form name="form1">
  <script>
    function pow(obj) {
      var x = Number(obj.x1.value);
      var n = Number(obj.n1.value);
      var result = 1;
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;

      }
      return result;
      obj.res.value = result;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
      result = '«действительного корня не существует»';
    } else {
      result = (pow(x, n));

    }
  </script>
  <input type="text1" name="x1" size=4>
  <input type="text2" name="n1" size=4>
  <input type="text3" name="res" size=4>
  <input type="button" value="Определить" onClick="pow(form1)">
</form>
```

Comment: у вас функция завершает свою работу до присвоения значения. Переменные x и n имеют область видимости только внутри функции. И условный оператор тоже никогда не выполнится.

Comment: а что исправить?

Comment: Вы определили функцию с одним параметром, а вызываете с двумя

Comment: пытались и через function pow (x,n) {

Comment: посмотрите внимательно на предупреждение : `Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined at stepen.html:56`

Comment: Оно означает, что в строке `if (n < 0) {` был встречена необъявленная переменная.

Comment: Вы объявили ее в функции, а пытаетесь использовать в глобальной области. Это невозможно, тк переменные, объявленные в функции видны только в ней.

Comment: перенес } получилось так

Comment: <form name="form1">
<script type="text/JavaScript">

    function pow(obj) {
    var x = Number(obj.x1.value);
    var n = Number(obj.n1.value);
        var result = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result *= x;
            
        }
        return result;
           obj.res.value=result;
    
    if (n < 0) {
       result='«действительного корня не существует»' ;
    } else {
       result=(pow(x, n));
    
    }
    }
     
</script>

Comment: Ошибок нету но и результата тоже

Comment: `return result; obj.res.value=result;` . Retun завершает работу функции, это значит, что весь код после него выполняться не будет

Comment: Во, сработало ) спасибо большое, и еще маленький вопрос, а чтобы вывести просто в форму а не в текстбокс мне нужно вместо obj.res.value=result;  написать document.write("="+result) ?

Answer (score 2):

По-моему должно быть так.

```js
function pow(obj) {
  var x = Number(obj.x1.value);
  var n = Number(obj.n1.value);
  if (n < 0) {
    result = '«действительного корня не существует»';
  } else {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      result *= x;
    }
    obj.res.value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text1" name="x1" size=4>
  <input type="text2" name="n1" size=4>
  <input type="text3" name="res" size=4>
  <input type="button" value="Определить" onClick="pow(form1)">
</form>
```

Comment: вас не смущает ретурн перед `obj.res.value = result;` ?

Comment: Ну да из-за него не работает. Исправил.